# Doubts in HDFS and Hadoop 1.0.3

Tags: macos, hadoop, hdfs

I am fairly new to Hadoop and I have been trying to setup my local machine and run few examples to understand how the process works. I have setup hadoop 1.0.3 on my MAC.I have a series of question and I will ask them as I describe what I done so far. I followed the instruction [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonwerner/archive/2011/11/13/how-to-set-up-hadoop-on-os-x-lion-10-7.aspx).

I though I was setting up Stand alone operation but ended up with a Pseudo Distribution. **Q1.) What is the difference ?**

Edited my .bash_profile

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/Library/hadoop-1.0.3
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Created passphraseless ssh to localhost on OS X. Then `$ ssh localhost`.

Then `$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format`. **Q2.) Should I format the namenode each time I start a new job and what gets formatted?**

Then `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh`.

I wanted to run the wordcount example. So I had to put the inputs in the HDFS. To do so I did `hadoop fs -mkdir WordCount_input`.

Q3.) **The docs [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/file_system_shell.html#ls) ask me to use `bin/hdfs dfs` so it would be `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir WordCount_input` but this gives me hdfs: command not found error?**

I used the **put** to place the files in HDFS.

```
hadoop dfs -put
/Users/yv/Documents/Hadoop-Workspace/file01
/Users/yv/Documents/Hadoop-Workspace/file02
/user/yv/WordCount_input
```

**Q4) Is it better to use the copyFromLocal instead of put ?**

**Q5.) These files that i created are in /user/yv/. Where exactly is /user/yv/ ?Are they inside the hadoop.tmp.dir location I specified in my core-site.xml**

Then I ran the example

> hadoop jar Documents/Hadoop-Workspace/wordcount.jar
>   org.myorg.WordCount /user/yv/WordCount_input/ output

So if I have to run the same example again I have to remove the output files and create a new one.

After running few example the datanodes did not have enough space? In the web interface for the NameNode under cluster summary everything became 0 (eg:DFS Remaining:0GB, Live Node : 0).Not sure why.

So I did `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh`. And reformated the namenode. Hence the namespaceID in of namenode and datanode became different. This is a problem.

So I had to delete my hadoop.tmp.dir and do everything from scrath

**Q.6)Could someone provide an easy solution if the datanode do not have enough space. How to free space ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe standalone mode runs entire jobs in one process, and pseudo-distributed simply splits the jobtracker and task nodes into separate processes just as they would be in a real cluster. Pseudo-distributed is probably the way to go for development.
2. You should not run format more than once. It initializes the namenode's metadata.
3. I'm not sure why it says that. `hadoop fs -mkdir WordCount_input` is what yo should use.
4. They are the same.
5. The data is stored in the location specified by the `dfs.data.dir` property in `hdfs-site.xml`. However, it may not be directly intelligible as HDFS uses a non-user-friendly directory and naming structure. If you wish to inspect the contents, you should use the `hadoop fs` commands.
6. This is entirely dependent on hardware. Nothing complicated is going on - if you have more files than you have room on your disk, there's nothing you can do except buy a bigger drive or delete files. For local dev/testing, you can also set `dfs.replication` to 1, but this is a very bad idea for a production system.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) See this page: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/single_node_setup.html, but in general Standalone will store all files on the local filesystem (no HDFS), and when you run a MapReduce job, you'll be running the job in a single JVM. There are limitations on what you can do in standalone mode (limited to a single reducer and no distributed cache for example).

Pseudo distributed mode means you are running a real Hadoop instance (NameNode, DataNode, Job Tracker, Task Tracker), but they are all run on the localhost. You have access to more features / functionality of hadoop (multiple reducers, distributed cache, HDFS etc), but lack some things that only come with a proper distributed cluster (data replication/redundancy, task failover)

Q2) You should only reformat the name node if you want to delete everything in HDFS (the distributed file system). You do not need to format it between jobs

Q3) This appears to be wrong in the documentation (maybe docs relating to Hadoop 2). There is no hdfs script in the bin folder (as per the error message you are seeing).

To create a directory you should use `bin/hadoop fs -mkdir WordCount_input`

Q4) The two commands are synonymous (`hadoop fs -help copyFromLocal` actually notes this in the help it displays)

Q5) They are stored in HDFS, you cannot find the files directly on the local file system, but they are stored in the location configured in hdfs-site.xml property `dfs.data.dir`, but the files are stored as blocks, and the namenode maintains a mapping between files names and block names.

Q6) How much room is available on the partition you have configured for the `dfs.data.dir`? If you have no space left on the disk then there isn't much you can do other free up space or move to a new partition.

Comment: So if I want to run a new map reduce program I can just delete the Input & output files in HDFS ?
I did not configure dfs.data.dir in my hdfs-site.xml.Is there a default location it assumes if I dont specify this?
If I stop my hadoop instance will the files in HDFS be deleted ?

Comment: Yes you can delete the output directory, or name a new output directory for each job. You don't need to delete the input data unless you no longer need it. If you didn't configure the location, look in the data-node log file for indication of where the default location is. If you stop HDFS, the files will persist and be available nect time HDFS is restarted

Comment: While running a job I saw something like this map 30% reduce 5%. I though the reducer waits for the mappers to finish before it starts. What does this mean ?

Comment: there's a slowstart configuration property which controls this, but if you have mappers that have finished, then there output can be copied to the nodes running your reducers to speed up the job (rather than waiting for all your mappers to finish and then copying the output)

Comment: I am not able to delete a jar from my recycle bin because it is still being used. I believe the jar is present in the datanode or the namenode as job.jar. How can i clean this if I want to run a new job ? You said formating namenode should be done once!!

Comment: By recycle you mean the trash folder in HDFS? You shouldn't need to do any of this if you want to run a new job, just recall `hadoop jar myjar.jar <other args...>`. Hadoop creates a tmp folder in HDFS for your job and uploads the job myjar.jar to it